# Get user created property from gettype

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation

I want to get the properties name from the class. 
I am using `GetType()` to get the property name but it is showing including system generated property like ... parent

```
 public  class Classtest : Activity
    {
        public int To { get; set; }
        public int From { get; set; }
    }

           Classtest testclass = new Classtest();

           foreach (Activity activity in testclass.Activities)
           {
               Type type = activity.GetType();
               PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = type.GetProperties();


               foreach (var p in propertyInfo)
               {                  
                   Console.WriteLine(p.Name);

                   prpoertyCount--;
               }
          }
```

Output I need only `From` and `To` property, but no system property like parent, name.

Comment: Was the answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 1):

In your case you got the properties from the base class becasue you get type from Activity: `activity.GetType();`

You should first get type of `Classtest`  and then get array pf properties. Just use:

```
Classtest testclass = new Classtest();
var propertyInfo = testclass.GetType().GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public
| System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
| System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);


foreach (var p in propertyInfo)
{                  
    Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
}
```

Here to the `GetProperties()` method I passed  a few binding flags. You can read more about that binding flags on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx)